# Flutter's demo app is not running.After some time it throws an error

Tags: android, flutter

When I run the flutter's demo app it got stuck at Running Gradle task 'assemble debug'...
When I run ./gradlew clean or ./gradlew build that also not works.
Note: I have installed JDK,android studio,android sdk in E drive and also set environment variables according to this.I have not installed visual studio(as it is for windows development.[Image of error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wj5T.jpg))

Answer (score 0):

Your ZIP file is corrupted.

One possibility, the Gradle wrapper probably was automatically downloaded, and there could be something like proxy or the web server probably throwing errors (e.g. wrapped in HTML page) and it was treated as the binary ZIP file.

Another possibility that I can think of, the .gradle folder was committed to SCM (Subversion/Git) with wrong type, the ZIP file should be a binary file, but somehow committed as a text file and there was some sort of conversion happening.